# How can I associate a subdomain to a Google Site?

Tags: web-applications, subdomain, google-sites

I wrote a website with Google Sites and associated it to a domain I own, let's call it .com. One of my associates is writing a Web app which will run on app..com. How can I build a Google Sites webpage associated to the subdomain? The instructions in Google Sites only explain how to associate a domain to a site or a page, not a subdomain.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom subdomain for your Google Site the same way as you can do for a custom domain. Go to your Google Site -> Settings -> Custom domains. Then you'll need to verify you own that subdomain from [Webmaster Central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en) or [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/).